# Implementing a Priority Stack with two stacks

Tags: java

This is how I think it's probably intended to work: You have Stack 1 that's sorted based on the priority and every time a new element comes along that should be in the middle of the stack, you pop out all the elements from Stack 1 onto Stack 2, add the element into place, and then pop all the elements from Stack 2 back to Stack 1.

Does anybody know a more efficient solution?

Comment: The concepts of Priority and Stack are somewhat contradictory?

Comment: Sorry, what is a "priority stack?"  How does it differ from a "priority queue?"  Is this a stack with fast access to the smallest element, or just a sequence where everything is in sorted order, or something totally different?

Comment: @both above, to be very honest - I've no idea myself. Yes, I found both the terms to contradicting as well. But the question was asked and it has to be answered :) I'm thinking it's expected to be in sorted order. Feel free to improve on my approach to the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What if one stack kept the odd priority items in order and the other stack kept the even priority items in order?

- On insert, you check which stack to insert to. You could still use the top of the other stack to hold items temporarily.
- On pop, you compare which stack has the higher priority item on top and pop that one.

In theory, wouldn't this roughly halve the number of operations (number of items needed to slide between stacks) to insert?

*Edit:*

As pointed out in the comments, this approach requires you have a good way of binning the priority values between the two stacks (your priority values implement a good hashCode()). Since priority values are often linear sequential, this approach may work.

Here's some code to play with:

- Original approach == Temp Holding Stack == ~45 lines
- Alternative approach (other answer) == Split Stack == ~50 lines
- Odd/Even Stack == ~76 lines

Typical Run:

```
...
Holding Stack Avg Moves = 1028.32 moves
Split Stack Avg Moves   = 747.85 moves
Odd/Even Stack Avg Moves    = 517.54 moves
```

Code:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.NoSuchElementException;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Stack;

public class PriorityStackProblem {

    private static final int NUMBER_OF_PASSES     = 100;
    private static final int MAX_START_STATE_SIZE = 100;
    private static final int MAX_OPERATIONS_SIZE  = 100;
    private static final int MAX_ITEM_VALUE       = 1000;

    public static abstract class MeasurableStack<T extends Comparable<? super T>> {

        protected int moves = 0;

        public abstract void load(final List<T> startState);
        public abstract void insert(final T value);
        public abstract T pop() throws NoSuchElementException;

        protected void move(
                final Stack<T> fromStack,
                final Stack<T> toStack) {
            toStack.push(fromStack.pop());
            moves++;
        }

        public void clearMoves() {
            moves = 0;
        }

        public int getMoves() {
            return moves;
        }

    }

    public static class TempHoldingStackApproach<T extends Comparable<? super T>>
    extends MeasurableStack<T> {

        private Stack<T> mainStack = new Stack<T>();
        private Stack<T> tempHoldingStack = new Stack<T>();

        @Override
        public void load(final List<T> startState) {
            mainStack.clear();
            tempHoldingStack.clear();
            clearMoves();
            T lastItem = null;
            for (final T item : startState) {
                mainStack.push(item);
                assert lastItem == null || item.compareTo(lastItem) >= 0;
                lastItem = item;
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void insert(final T value) {
            // slide higher priority items on main stack to temp stack
            while (!mainStack.isEmpty() && mainStack.peek().compareTo(value) > 0) {
                move(mainStack, tempHoldingStack);
            }

            assert mainStack.isEmpty() || mainStack.peek().compareTo(value) <= 0;
            assert tempHoldingStack.isEmpty() || tempHoldingStack.peek().compareTo(value) >= 0;

            mainStack.push(value);

            // slide them back
            while (!tempHoldingStack.isEmpty()) {
                move(tempHoldingStack, mainStack);
            }

            assert tempHoldingStack.isEmpty();
        }

        @Override
        public T pop() throws NoSuchElementException {
            assert tempHoldingStack.isEmpty();
            return mainStack.pop(); // will throw if empty
        }

    }

    public static class SplitStackApproach<T extends Comparable<? super T>>
    extends MeasurableStack<T> {

        private Stack<T> lowerStack = new Stack<T>();
        private Stack<T> higherStack = new Stack<T>();

        @Override
        public void load(final List<T> startState) {
            lowerStack.clear();
            higherStack.clear();
            clearMoves();
            T lastItem = null;
            for (final T item : startState) {
                lowerStack.push(item);
                assert lastItem == null || item.compareTo(lastItem) >= 0;
                lastItem = item;
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void insert(final T value) {
            // only one of the while loops below should really execute

            // slide any higher priority items on lower stack to higher stack
            while (!lowerStack.isEmpty() && lowerStack.peek().compareTo(value) > 0) {
                move(lowerStack, higherStack);
            }

            // slide any lower priority items on higher stack to lower stack
            while (!higherStack.isEmpty() && higherStack.peek().compareTo(value) < 0) {
                move(higherStack, lowerStack);
            }

            assert lowerStack.isEmpty() || lowerStack.peek().compareTo(value) <= 0;
            assert higherStack.isEmpty() || higherStack.peek().compareTo(value) >= 0;

            lowerStack.push(value);
        }

        @Override
        public T pop() throws NoSuchElementException {
            // get to highest priority item
            while (!higherStack.isEmpty()) {
                move(higherStack, lowerStack);
            }

            assert higherStack.isEmpty();
            return lowerStack.pop(); // will throw if empty
        }

    }

    public static class OddEvenStackApproach<T extends Comparable<? super T>>
    extends MeasurableStack<T> {

        private Stack<T> oddStack = new Stack<T>();
        private Stack<T> evenStack = new Stack<T>();

        @Override
        public void load(final List<T> startState) {
            oddStack.clear();
            evenStack.clear();
            clearMoves();
            for (final T item : startState) {
                if (item.hashCode() % 2 == 1) {
                    oddStack.push(item);
                } else {
                    evenStack.push(item);
                }
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void insert(final T value) {
            if (value.hashCode() % 2 == 1) {
                insert(value, oddStack, evenStack);
            } else {
                insert(value, evenStack, oddStack);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public T pop() throws NoSuchElementException {
            if (oddStack.size() <= 0) {
                return evenStack.pop();  // will throw if empty
            } else if (evenStack.size() <= 0) {
                return oddStack.pop();  // will throw if empty
            } else {
                final T oddTop = oddStack.peek();
                final T evenTop = evenStack.peek();
                if (oddTop.compareTo(evenTop) >= 0) {
                    return oddStack.pop();  // will throw if empty
                } else {
                    return evenStack.pop();  // will throw if empty
                }
            }
        }

        private void insert(
                final T value,
                final Stack<T> targetStack,
                final Stack<T> tempHoldingStack) {
            final int oldTargetStackSize = targetStack.size();
            final int oldHoldingStackSize = tempHoldingStack.size();

            int movedItems = 0;

            // slide any higher priority items on target stack to holding stack
            while (!targetStack.isEmpty() && targetStack.peek().compareTo(value) > 0) {
                move(targetStack, tempHoldingStack);
                movedItems++;
            }

            assert targetStack.isEmpty() || targetStack.peek().compareTo(value) <= 0;
            assert movedItems == 0 || tempHoldingStack.peek().compareTo(value) >= 0;

            targetStack.push(value);

            // slide items back
            while (movedItems > 0) {
                move(tempHoldingStack, targetStack);
                movedItems--;
            }

            assert targetStack.size() == oldTargetStackSize + 1;
            assert tempHoldingStack.size() == oldHoldingStackSize;
        }

    }

    private static List<Integer> generateStartState(final Random random) {
        final int size = random.nextInt(MAX_START_STATE_SIZE-1);
        final List<Integer> startState = new ArrayList<Integer>(size);
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
            startState.add(random.nextInt(MAX_ITEM_VALUE-1));
        }
        Collections.sort(startState);
        return startState;
    }

    private static List<Integer> generateOperations(
            final Random random,
            final int startStateSize) {
        final int size = random.nextInt(MAX_OPERATIONS_SIZE-1);
        final List<Integer> operations = new ArrayList<Integer>(size);
        int count = startStateSize;
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
            if (count > 0 && random.nextInt(2) == 0) {
                // null means pop
                operations.add(null);
                count--;
            } else {
                // non-null means insert the item
                operations.add(random.nextInt(MAX_ITEM_VALUE-1));
                count++;
            }
        }
        return operations;
    }

    private static <T extends Comparable<? super T>> int execute(
            final List<T> startState,
            final List<T> operations,
            final MeasurableStack<T> stack) {
        System.out.print(stack.getClass().getSimpleName()+" Moves:\t");
        stack.load(startState);
        for (final T item : operations) {
            if (item == null) {
                stack.pop();
            } else {
                stack.insert(item);
            }
            System.out.print(item+" ("+stack.getMoves()+") ");
        }
        System.out.println();
        return stack.getMoves();
    }

    private static float average(final int[] results) {
        int total = 0;
        for (final int moves : results) {
            total += moves;
        }
        return total / (float) results.length;
    }

    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        final Random random = new Random();

        final int[] holdingStackResults = new int[NUMBER_OF_PASSES];
        final int[] splitStackResults   = new int[NUMBER_OF_PASSES];
        final int[] oddEvenStackResults = new int[NUMBER_OF_PASSES];

        for (int pass = 0; pass < NUMBER_OF_PASSES; pass++) {

            final List<Integer> startState = generateStartState(random);
            final List<Integer> operations = generateOperations(random, startState.size());

            System.out.println("Start State ["+startState.size()+"]:\t"+startState);
            System.out.println("Operations ["+operations.size()+"]:\t"+operations);
            System.out.println();

            System.out.println("Moves: item (moves) item (moves) ...\t");

            holdingStackResults[pass] =
                execute(startState, operations, new TempHoldingStackApproach());

            splitStackResults[pass] =
                execute(startState, operations, new SplitStackApproach());

            oddEvenStackResults[pass] =
                execute(startState, operations, new OddEvenStackApproach());

            System.out.println();
            System.out.println(
                    "Holding: \t" + holdingStackResults[pass] + " total moves\n" +
                    "Split:   \t" + splitStackResults[pass]   + " total moves\n" +
                    "Odd/Even:\t" + oddEvenStackResults[pass] + " total moves");
            System.out.println("---");

        }

        System.out.println("Holding Stack Results:\t"+Arrays.toString(holdingStackResults));
        System.out.println("Split Stack Results:\t"+Arrays.toString(splitStackResults));
        System.out.println("Odd/Even Stack Results:\t"+Arrays.toString(oddEvenStackResults));
        System.out.println();

        final float holdingStackAverage = average(holdingStackResults);
        final float splitStackAverage   = average(splitStackResults);
        final float oddEvenStackAverage = average(oddEvenStackResults);

        System.out.println("Holding Stack Avg Moves\t\t= "  + holdingStackAverage+" moves");
        System.out.println("Split Stack Avg Moves\t\t= "  + splitStackAverage+" moves");
        System.out.println("Odd/Even Stack Avg Moves\t= " + oddEvenStackAverage+" moves");
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you assuming that the objects are all Integers or that some mechanism exists to discern objects into the 2 stacks? I don't know if a distinction can be guaranteed like that.

Comment: @user183037 - yes, you're right, I'm assuming integer, but I suppose hashCode() would work if you know your objects have a proper hashCode implementation - which makes sense, since hashCode() is traditionally used for partition objects into buckets, or in this case, stacks.

Comment: Agreed, hashCode() is perfect. Thanks again - this is probably the best answer I've seen in StackOverflow yet. An improvement of 100% is pretty awesome!

Answer (score 4):

The only thing I can think of to make it more efficient is to leave the items split in between the two stacks after an insert.

1. If the next operation is insert (and not an insert of a new highest priority item), then you saved the effort moving items back from stack 2 back to stack 1 after the last insert only to have to move it back to stack 2 for the next insert.
2. If the next operation is pop or its a insert of a new highest priority item, then you move the items back from stack 2 to stack 1 - which we were doing anyway in the original solution, so there's no wasted effort.

*Edit:*

I was curious about the "complexity" (casual, not cyclomatic) of this alternative, so here's some thrown-together untested code for visual comparison:

Note: larger value == higher priority

Original impl:

```
public void insert(int value) {

  // slide higher priority items on lower stack to higher stack temporarily
  while (! lowerStack.isEmpty() && lowerStack.peek() > value) {
    higherStack.push(lowerStack.pop());
  }

  assert lowerStack.isEmpty() || lowerStack.peek() <= value;
  assert higherStack.isEmpty() || higherStack.peek() >= value);

  lowerStack.push(value);

  // slide them back
  while (! higherStack.isEmpty()) {
    lowerStack.push(higherStack.pop());
  }

  assert higherStack.isEmpty();

}

public int pop() throws NoSuchElementException {

  assert higherStack.isEmpty();
  return lowerStack.pop();  // will throw if empty

}
```

Alternate impl:

```
public void insert(int value) {

  // only one of the while loops below should really execute

  // slide any higher priority items on lower stack to higher stack
  while (! lowerStack.isEmpty() && lowerStack.peek() > value) {
    higherStack.push(lowerStack.pop());
  }

  // slide any lower priority items on higher stack to lower stack
  while (! higherStack.isEmpty() && higherStack.peek() < value) {
    lowerStack.push(higherStack.pop());
  }

  assert lowerStack.isEmpty() || lowerStack.peek() <= value;
  assert higherStack.isEmpty() || higherStack.peek() >= value);

  lowerStack.push(value);

}


public T pop() throws NoSuchElementException {

  // get to highest priority item
  while (! higherStack.isEmpty()) {
    lowerStack.push(higherStack.pop());
  }

  assert higherStack.isEmpty();
  return lowerStack.pop();  // will throw if empty

}
```

Comment: +1: I actually thought of that as I came up with the explanation, but I figured it was going to be a little too cumbersome to track and that I'd probably be opening myself to too many related questions since it's left in a "transient" state.

Comment: Point taken - I was thinking all along of 1 "main" stack and a secondary side-kick stack. But the implementation of 2 "equally important" stacks should definitely be more efficient. Thanks for hashing the code together - that helped a lot!

Comment: @user183037 - the devil is so often in the details, I think I needed to write it down to convince myself whether I was missing some gotcha in my head.

Answer (score 0):

If it is a interview question, maybe you are expected to answer "*Stack doesn't have priority at all. It's priority queue.*":)

Comment: I doubt if this was a "trick" question, and if you look at my approach, it's technically possible. Not clean/efficient when you look at available data structures for the same purpose, but under the circumstances - possible.

Comment: yes, that is what I guess. Something like     "Could tell me how to implement a method in interface in Java?"

Answer (score -1):

You don't need to use a Stack internally just because you're presenting a stack as your external interface (encapsulation!). Just insert into the middle of whatever collection you're using.

Comment: Given the "interview-questions" tag, I suspect that the artificial constraint is to use two stacks!

Comment: @Oli Charlesworth: True - I think I'm pretty much going to have to use 2 stacks.
@Anon.: Could you please elaborate on that a bit more though - I'm sure I could use something like that in a realistic scenario.

Comment: @Oli: In an interview, I'd specifically call out that an interface doesn't constrain what your internal implementation should be.

Comment: @user183037: The whole point of OOP is that consumers of your class don't need to know how it's implemented under the hood - they have an interface (objects go in, and come back out in priority order), and you're free to do whatever you want as long as you satisfy the constraints of that interface.

Comment: Yet the idea in such an **interview question** is to use the stack abstraction nicely, isn't it ? Not to replace it with a more convenient collection.

Comment: @Dunaril: The point of OOP is that you can replace it with a more convenient collection whenever you feel like it, and anyone actually using your class won't notice a thing.

Comment: But the OP is not willing to implement a class, he is willing to solve an algorithmic problem..

Comment: @Dunaril: The question itself is "implement a priority stack".

Comment: @Anon., while I fully agree with your standpoint in a real-world scenario, as @Oli Charlesworth and @Dunaril pointed out though, this was an interview question and we're bound by the options we're provided.